# What is this traffic?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, dmesg

My Computer seems to be doing something that the firewall (UFW) is blocking.
from dmesg:

```
[207683.801389] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:51c2:a242:da77:ce8f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=155038 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24
```

There is a bunch of those, and Im not sure why. I look at dmesg frequently,  and this is a recent development. From ifconfig, I know my Ethernet port is enp0s25, and just enough about IPV6, to know that "ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001" All nodes addresses. Should I be concerned? how should I go about geting  more info about where this traffic is coming from?

Ubuntu Mate, 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colord` regularly sends those discovery packets in IPv4/6 as well:

```
IN= OUT=vboxnet0 SRC=192.168.79.1 DST=192.168.79.255 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22720 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 UID=107 GID=113
```

They also get logged for my UserID when launching `simple-scan` resulting in sane network-scanner discovery.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your computer is trying to send a network discovery packet looking for Canon network enabled printers. Here is what makes me think that:

- A UDP packet is being sent to broadcast, so it is some form of network discovery.
- The destination port (DPT) is 8612, which is associated with Canon network printers. (see the [IANA entry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=8612) for this port)

Comment: I just installed one, at the office.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get similar message with a wireless printer on the network, so shouldn't be anything to worry about.